# NavLink color is not changing using tailwind css

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, tailwind-css

```
<NavLink
  to={item.link}
  key={index}
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "text-oirOrange" : ' ')}
>
  <li className='cursor-pointer font-semibold text-oirBrown hover:text-oirOrange'>
    {item.text}
  </li>
</NavLink>
```

The active nav link color should change, but it is not changing. `"text-oirOrange"` class is getting added to the html but it is not affecting.

"oirOrange" is color that I have already declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question/issue correctly you are wanting to add this `"text-oiOrange"` class to the list item (*`li`*) element, e.g. the text that is actually displayed. You can use the `children` render function for this to apply the active styling to the `li` element instead of the anchor tag that `NavLink` is rendering.

Example:

```
<NavLink to={item.link} key={index}>
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <li
      className={[
        "cursor-pointer font-semibold hover:text-oirOrange",
        isActive ? "text-oirOrange" : "text-oirBrown"
      ].join(" ")}
    >
      {item.text}
    </li>

  )}
</NavLink>
```